# Логическое отрицание. Непонятки в понимании.

Tags: логика

Собственно вопрос. Есть, допустим, число 9. В двоичном представлении = 1001. Если логическое отрицание инвертирует разряды, то из 1001 должно получиться 0110. Однако шарп, питон и остальные языки программирования возвращают -1010 (-10 в десятичной). В чём подвох?

Comment: Это называется не логическое отрицание, а побитовое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подвох в том, что число хранится не в виде 1001, а как минимум 00001001 (если тип переменной байт). Если тип целый, то там будет и 32 бита. И все они инвертируются.

А вот почему получается -10 - это просто, нужно вспомнить, как хранятся отрицательные числа - в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)). И если самый левый бит единица, то это будет отрицательное число.

Comment: Тоесть, по сути, все представления чисел в ЕВМ представляются в виде дополнительного кода, а не в виде обыкновенных(для человека) двоичных чисел?

Comment: Минут десять ломал голову, что это за представление такое - ЕВМ. А это просто ЭВМ:)

В большинстве современных компьютеров числа представлены в виде битов - нулей и единиц. А как  их будет интрепретировать пользователь (или среда исполнения) - дело десятое.